# how to write the query to display the toys whose name contains 'DM'?

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc

thisis my code when i press the runnable i got nothing only (connected)
and i wanna display the toys whose name contains 'DM'

```
import java.sql.*;
public class Toy {
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
String query = "SELECT ToyName, Price, color from Toy WHERE ToyName='DM '";
System.out.println("concected");
Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:\\Users\\96650\\Documents\\toy.accdb");
Statement stmt = c.createStatement();   
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
while(rs.next()) {
            String desc = rs.getString("ToyName");
            String color = rs.getString("Color");
            double price=rs.getDouble("Price");
            System.out.println(desc+"  Color: "+color+"\n $"+price);}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your SQL query is wrong. The current query will select the toys with `toyName == 'DM '` wich is I think is not what you want.

To get all toys whose name contains 'DM' you need to use `LIKE` so update your sql query to be like this :

```
String query = "SELECT ToyName, Price, color from Toy WHERE ToyName LIKE '%DM%'";
```